# Using the Object from external javascript file inside Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have script tag like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/foo.min.js"></script>
```

And then I just want to use the object from that `js` file inside my `typescript` like below

```
Foo.create('element', {
    "title": "foo",
    "description": "bar",
});
```

I got the error warning on `Foo` inside my `Typescript`. Is there any way that I can use `Foo` object like `Javascript`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare var Foo: any;
```

You can get more specific than `any` if you wish, providing better typing information, but this should get you started.

Comment: I got error like `Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected` for `declare`

Comment: @SeizeDuh where did you put your `declare` statement?

Comment: Now I realised I should put that on top.